# How to update a cell in Excel VBA with NOW time for a another cell update which in turn was updated via other cell changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update Cell E2 with `Now()`, for any value change in cell `D2`.

Note `D2` value depends on many other cells like `A2, B2 and C2`.

I tried `Worksheet_Change`, but this triggers for manual update, also the cell which I need to update `E2` is updated automatically (i.e. not via manual update).

Any solution, where cells `A2`, `B2` and `C2` are getting live feeds and `D2 has a formula based on them, is acceptable.

Now if `D2` changes, I need `E2` with `Now()`  date and time.

Comment: Try `=IF(D2=0,"","")&NOW()` or `=LEFT(D2,0)&NOW()`

Comment: Or look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35051903/5461205)

Comment: Can you be more elobrate??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Calculate* event with a memory variable:

```
Public OldD2 As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   If Range("D2").Value <> OldD2 Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
         Range("E2").Value = Now
         OldD2 = Range("D2").Value
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I understand this works for single cell, but i need this for whole E column

Comment: @SaraVaNan  I apologize for not seeing your need in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the Precedent property of the Range object.

I checked if the changed cell is part of my precedent, if so then using the Row of the Target (changed cell), i moved to my required Column (which is static) did my logic.

Thanks,
Sara

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim keycells As Range
 Set keycells = Sheets("FUT_CALLS-1").Range("AD1:AD1").EntireColumn

If Not Intersect(Target, keycells.Precedents) Is Nothing Then

```
If (Sheets("FUT_CALLS-1").Cells(Target.Row, 30).Value = "BUY" Or Sheets("FUT_CALLS-1").Cells(Target.Row, 30).Value = "SELL") And Sheets("FUT_CALLS-1").Cells(Target.Row, 30).Value <> Sheets("MyCodeSheet").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value Then
   Sheets("FUT_CALLS-1").Cells(Target.Row, 32).Value = Now()
   Sheets("MyCodeSheet").Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Sheets("FUT_CALLS-1").Cells(Target.Row, 30).Value

End If
```

End If
End Sub